# display inline not working for navigation buttons

Tags: css, button, navigation, inline

I am going nuts, what am I missing, something obvious I am sure, to make my nav buttons stack next to each other inline and not on top of each other. When I tried using display: inline they all got real tiny like slivers!

http://awesomenesslabs.com/staging/brenna-resp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `UL` and `LI` CSS to this:

```
ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    display: block;
}
li {
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#navbar > ul > li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class like this.

```
#navbar ul li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

and your work tab hover position should be

```
.nav-work-button:hover {
    background-position: 0 -47px; 
}
```